# Is there a callback when the FutureBuilder is done building in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to know when all the widgets are built in Flutter including FutureBuilder widgets.  `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` is called when build is done, but before FutureBuilder is built.

I have a List inside a FutureBuilder whose data is fetched from the server. There is another Text widget outside FutureBuilder which shows the count of list items. I need to update this count widget when the list is populated .Without using a stream is there a callback method triggered when the FutureBuilder is built.

Comment: Future builder builds when the future completes. could you share more info about your exact use case?

Comment: it smells like a typical [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), what do you need it for?

Comment: @pskink :- I have a List inside a FutureBuilder whose data is fetched from the server. There is another Text widget outside FutureBuilder which shows the count of list elements. I need to update this count widget when the list is populated.

Comment: what stops you from including those two widgets inside `FutureBuilder`? (or using two `FutureBuilder`s if you really need it)

Comment: @pskink:- UI design constraints, but this of course is a solution. What I need to know is, similar to 'Widget.instance.addPostFrameCallback', which is called when the build method is finished(doesn't check for the FutureBuilder). is there a callback when the FutureBuilder is also completed.

Comment: what UI design constraints? it will look and behave *exactly the same* - do not use any workarounds with post frame callbacs

Answer (score 7):

Just use `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` in your futurebuilder when has data and connection is done

```
FutureBuilder<List<Object>>(
    future: _listFuture,
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      
      if(snapshot.hasData && snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
        WidgetsBinding.instance
            .addPostFrameCallback((_) {
              
        });
      }

      return ...
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways. If you intend to do this without using state management, you could use ValueNotifier.

```
ValueNotifier<int> total = ValueNotifier(0);

FutureBuilder()..future.then((snapshot) {
                  total.value = snapshot.total;
                });

ValueListenableBuilder(
            valueListenable: total,
            builder: (context, value, widget) {
              return Text(value.toString());
            },
          ),
```

Bu i suggest you use [provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)

Comment: Thanks for the response, So there is no available call back similar to 'addPostFrameCallback'. And we'll have to do this using other means like ValueNotifier or Streams.

Comment: @NasfiU, no - you dont need any extra `ValueNotifier`s nor `Stream`s - either use one `FutureBuilder` that builds both widgets in its `builder`callback or use two independent `FutureBuilder`s

Comment: @pskink :- I agree, but what if some logic is to be applied when whole UI is built. How do we know the layout is finished?. something similar as 'viewDidLayoutSubviews()' in iOS.

Comment: @NasfiU use [Future](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html) api then - you need to use the same `Future` that you are passing to `FutureBuilder`

Comment: `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` in flutter lets you know when the build method is finished. But this doesn't wait for the FutureBuilder to finish the layout. @pskink

Comment: @pskink :- What if we have multiple FutureBuilders with multiple Future methods.

Comment: @NasfiU so read carefully  `Future` class official [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html)

Comment: @pskink: - I've gone through the Future class, but that doesn't give any information on FutureBuilder callbacks.
Let me sort the question again.
Assume I have 5 `FutureBuilder` widgets whose `future` refers to 5 different `Future` methods. And i need to do something when all this 5 `FutureBuilder layout is completed.

Comment: @pskink:- 5 different independent server API calls in one screen and 5 different widgets whose data is depended on the response.

Comment: @pskink:- If these widgets were static and doesn't have any `FutureBuilders`. I would use `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` to know when the build method is done and the UI layout is finished.

Comment: @NasfiU everything is in the official `Future` documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/wait.html - *"Waits for multiple futures to complete and collects their results.

Returns a future which will complete once all the provided futures have completed, either with their results, or with an error if any of the provided futures fail."*